# Using POST with Query JSON and iterating MySQL results

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here.

I'm trying to have a table of data change when a user clicks on a different item quantity.

I might be using the $.each() method incorrectly, because i'm not seeing any results on the page and i'm a complete jQuery noob. I appreciate any help, thanks

test-table.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function swapContent(count){
            $(".price-sidebar").html("Put animation here").show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
                url: "myphpscript.php",
                data: {countVar: count},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#content').empty();

                    $.each(data, function(){
                        $("#content").append("<tr>");
                        $("#content").append("<td class='store-row'><h5 property='seller'>"+this[MerchantName]+"</h5></td>");
                        $("#content").append("<td class='price-row'><h5 property='price'>$"+this[Price]+"</h5></td>");
                        $("#content").append("<td><a property='url' target='_blank' href='"+this[PageURL]+"' class='btn btn-danger'>GET IT</a></td>");
                        $("#content").append("</tr>");
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('18');">18</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('48');">48</a>
        <a href="#" onClick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('96');">96</a>

        <section class="price-sidebar span8" > 
        <div property="offers" typeof="Offer">               
            <h2>Price Comparison</h2>
            </br>
            <table class="price-data">
                <tr>
                    <th class='store-row'><h4>Store</h4></th>
                    <th class='price-row'><h4>Price</h4></th>
                </tr>
                <div id="content">

                </div>
            </table><!--end price-data-->
           </div><!--end offers-->
        </section><!--end price sidebar-->
    </body>
```

myphpscript.php

```
 <?php
    $countVar = $_POST['countVar'];

    $data = PriceCompare($countVar);
    echo json_encode($data);

    function PriceCompare($countVar){
        $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=--','---','---');
        $STH = $DBH->query('SELECT ProductID, MerchantName, Price, PageURL
                            FROM merchants
                            WHERE ProductID=677 AND Count=' . $countVar . '
                            ORDER BY Price');
        $result = $STH->fetchAll();

        return $result;
       }
    ?>
```

Comment: are you sure your $.ajax post is working? Have you tried making an error: function to check the status?

Comment: In the php script I tested it by replacing $countVar with test data and it returned JSON data. Is that what you are referring too?

Comment: Have you fired up your developer tools (javascript console) to see if your java-script is erroring out?  Side note:  you might want to look into using PDO with prepared statements.  Your sql code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: I was referring to the `error:` option for $.ajax. and accessing the `response.status` or `response.responseText` in it. It's good practice to do something on error anyway so you know if there is an issue

Comment: CountMurphy, no I don't use a javascript console, just Sublime Text 2. I know that my SQL is vulnerable, I planned on fixing that after I solved this mystery. Nick, no I will try to look into that. This is my first time writing jQuery or JSON, I've only learned PHP. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @MitchGlenn, I think you misunderstood about the console.  I meant did you open it in your browser and see if you gave you any run errors?  If you use chrome, try this: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Comment: @CountMurphy, yes I definitely misunderstood you and yes I do use Chrome. I did that and the run error it gave me was this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (test-table.html:14) 

That is the line for the url:"myphpscript.php"
But I don't know why that would be giving an error.

Comment: @MitchGlenn The `dataType: 'json'` line doesn't have a comma at the end.

Comment: Wow you guys are great, all fixed! Thanks. I should have read your solution more carefully Jason.

Comment: @JasonP One more question, if I were to want to set the first buttons results (lowest quantity) as the default when a user first comes to the page, how would I go about that? Right now it shows an empty table and the user would have to push a button to show anything.

Comment: @MitchGlenn I just added that to my answer after posting the comment. You didn't miss it the first time.

Comment: @MitchGlenn If you gave your links a class, you could do something like this: `$(document).ready(function() { $('.linkClass').eq(0).click(); })` which would simulate a click on the first link with that class. I would also recommend binding the events as click events, and doing so with jQuery instead of inline.

Comment: @JasonP I added a class of "linkClass" to each <a> tag and added your line of code right before the first function swapContent. Nothing has happened when I refreshed though, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's possible that `click()` doesn't trigger a mousedown event. Try changing your `onmousedown` events to click events. See the edit I made to my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three issues:

1. Your `dataType: 'json'` line doesn't have a comma at the end.
2. Access your data like `this.MerchantName`. Doing `this[MerchantName]` would be valid if you had defined a variable called `MerchantName`.
3. You were appending a `<tr>` to `#content`, then appending a `<td>` to `#content`, instead of appending the `<td>` to the `<tr>`.

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function () {
    $("#content").append(
        $("<tr/>")
            .append("<td class='store-row'><h5 property='seller'>" + this.MerchantName + "</h5></td>");
            .append("<td class='price-row'><h5 property='price'>$" + this.Price + "</h5></td>");
            .append("<td><a property='url' target='_blank' href='" + this.PageURL + "' class='btn btn-danger'>GET IT</a></td>")
    );
})
```